Improving performance of remote command execution on Exchange Server using SSH
My basic requirement is to integrate/ connect with on-premise exchange server and perform
CRUD operations. I want to use Java to implement this client. This Java client will be running on a Unix machine that is not within the network/ domain of the exchange server. The client will be running remotely, possibly AWS EC2 instance or anything else.
Note: The client will somehow be able to access a Windows machine (let us call this host A) that is within the domain (that is not of importance here, but mentioning this for sake of completeness), also:

Powershell remoting using WinRM/ WSMan is not supported on Unix based clients
Hence, I won't be able to use it.

Following are the options that I have:

Use SSH to connect to Host-A
Once the SSH connection is formed, using powershell I will be able to connect to on-premise ExchangeServer using powershell remoting features

Here are few things that I have tried from my MacOS machine's terminal:
> ssh Administrator@172.18.52.49
// SSH is successful and now I am connected to Host-A. Now I open a powershell on that machine
> pwsh 
> $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://HOSTB.EX2019.lab/PowerShell -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Credentials;
> Import-PSSession $session -DisableNameChecking;
> Measure-Command { Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited | Out-Host }

To get the complete output on my MacOS's terminal, it barely takes ~ 15 seconds and is available almost instantaneously.
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 13

Now I want to replicate this using Java. I am using JSCH, but the performance is very very low. Here is the code:
Session session = new JSch().getSession("Administrator", "172.18.52.49", 22);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword("Password");

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
session.connect();

ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
StringBuilder commandBuilder = new StringBuilder();

//... I append/ club all the commands that I want to execute as a single unit
commandBuilder.append("$username = \\\"Administrator\\\"; ");
commandBuilder.append("$password = \\\"Password\\\"; ");
commandBuilder.append("$encryptedPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force; ");
commandBuilder.append("$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $encryptedPassword); ");
commandBuilder.append("$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://HOSTB.EX2019.lab/PowerShell -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Credentials; ");
commandBuilder.append("Import-PSSession $session -DisableNameChecking -CommandName Get-Mailbox; ");
commandBuilder.append("Measure-Command {Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited | Out-host}; ");

channel.setCommand(
            "pwsh -command \"" + commandBuilder + "\"");

ByteArrayOutputStream outputBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream errorBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
InputStream err = channel.getExtInputStream();

//long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
channel.connect();


// Logic to read the output goes here
.....
.....

System.out.println("output: " + outputBuffer.toString("UTF-8"));
System.out.println("error: " + errorBuffer.toString("UTF-8"));

channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


 System.out.println("Total time between session connection and disconnection with Get-Mailbox command: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");

This piece of code takes ~420 seconds which is 7 minutes which is very very high.
I also tried with:
 session.setConfig("compression.s2c", "zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none");
 session.setConfig("compression.c2s", "zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none");
 session.setConfig("compression_level", "5");

And
 session.setConfig("ReceiveBufferSize", "65536");
 session.setConfig("SendBufferSize", "65536");

But nothing is working that can improve the performance. What am I doing wrong? Are there any other approaches that I can use?
Need some pointers here

P.S: I also tried opening "shell" session, but the observation is same

Update 1:
This is the remaining part that reads the output
byte[] tmp = new byte[65536];
    while (true) {
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 65536);
            if (i < 0) break;
            outputBuffer.write(tmp, 0, i);
        }
        while (err.available() > 0) {
            int i = err.read(tmp, 0, 65536);
            if (i < 0) break;
            errorBuffer.write(tmp, 0, i);
        }
        if (channel.isClosed()) {
            if ((in.available() > 0) || (err.available() > 0)) 
                 continue;
            System.out.println("exit-status: " + 
                     channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
}


You are not sharing the full code, how are we supposed to know what are you doing? Read [ask]. But you should be profiling the code yourself to identify the part that is taking more time, then ask a question more focused into that part.

If you are running the same script remotely and taking a lot longer it is probably the connection speed that is slowing you down not the query.  You can use ping to test the network speed.  I like using large packets with ping which better reports errors.  On windows I use Ping -t -l 65500 IPaddress.  Slow speed can also be cause by low memory or not enough disk space (slow disk) if output is going to disk.

@jdweng The problem is that, the following is quick: Mac Machine's terminal -> SSH to Host A -> Remote PowerShell to Exchange Server -> execute Get-Mailbox but, the same using java client:  Mac Machine's (jsch java client) -> SSH to Host A -> Remote PowerShell to Exchange Server -> execute Get-Mailbox is taking a lot of time

@aled I have updated the question with the remaining part...That is the whole code that I have....

See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520393/performance-takes-a-hit-while-using-java-jsch-exec-vs-shell-to-run-multiple

@jdweng I followed the link, but that is not the issue. As you can see in the code, I have concatenated all the commands and provided as single to exec, so in my case,  the shell will be created only once and not multiple times

What difference does it make that you have only one command.  The link says "The "exec" channel runs the command in an isolated environment (typically a new shell instance)".  The isolated environment runs slow.

Just to note, I had already tried with "shell" with no performance improvement.
When we do with "shell" it opens a new environment as well which is just like "exec" except, "shell" is persistent and allows to run multiple commands.
But that not the scenario here...May be I (we) have to look in to the read part (that I added later ) if that is causing the issue or not
